# Is it possible from within a thread in C/C++ to get a parent thread id if it wasn't passed in as an argument on pthread_create?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

`pthread_self()` is to get your own thread id. It doesn't seem like you can get the thread id of the thread which spawned you unless it was given to you during spawning. Or is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all threads are equal in POSIX threads, there is no hierarchy. Even the thread that executes `main` has no special role and can be terminated without effecting the others.